# any appropriate word in english for 'Khushi & Gum'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What can I say  'Khushi & Gum' in single or appropriate word in english. Here  'Khushi & Gum' is from Hindi language.

Comment: My Hindi is a little weak.  What does that mean?

Comment: Or at least please explain the situation in which you might use that Hindi phrase, so that we native English speakers can come up with some apt alternatives in English.

Comment: This is an _English_ site, not a Hindi site. Not everybody in the world speaks Hindi—in fact, only a small handful of our regular users here do. If you're asking for an equivalent of a Hindi word or phrase, you're going to have to tell us what it means and how it's used, with examples. I mean, would you be able to help me if I asked you what the Hindi equivalent of the Irish _mála easóg_ is, with no further information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Khushi aur gham" literally translates to "happiness and sadness". A few words that can approximate the effect in Hindi are :

- > bittersweet (the closest in meaning)
- > ambivalence/ambivalent
- > mirth and melancholy

Hope it helps :)